# How to calculate effective resistance for weighted directed graph?

Tags: r, matrix, graph-theory

I need to calculate the resistance matrix of a weighted directed graph by using a reduced laplacian matrix.

I have the definition of the resistance here : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.5163.pdf (definition 2)

But I would like to make a code in R to calculate resistance between all pairs of nodes in a large graph (600 nodes). 
I don't have enough mathematical knowledge to fully understand the calculation and to write the code.

I have the laplacian matrix of the graph with Laplacian_matrix function from igraph package but I don't know how to do the others steps...

Can you help me to write the code ? Or do you know a package to do this with R or Python ?